# XML file header

Tags: sql, xml, header

I have an XML file that I've created with an SQL query. I need to add a header line to it. The header line is something like:

```
<XMLImport RecordCount="50"... >
```

This is includes a record count. This is part of a larger query. How would I go about getting a record count and including it in the header so that it is part of the XML file?

Thank you for any feedback on this.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.